# Is multithreading a time sharing or parallel processing?

Tags: multithreading

Is multithreading a time sharing or parallel processing?
Please explain me if CPU is multi core processor

Comment: from programming point of view,  time sharing looks very similar to parallel processing. You should not care the difference.

Comment: from programming point of view, multicore processor is a set of multiple processors. You cannot determine a difference.